# Windows VC++ 2010 link error _main

Tags: visual-c++

I was trying to poll available devices on a Windows machine by this code example from Microsoft. But there are link errors that relates to _main().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <regstr.h>

   int main( int argc, char *argv[ ], char *envp[ ] )
   {
   HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
   SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
   DWORD i;

   // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
   hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,
       0, // Enumerator
       0,
       DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES );

   if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       // Insert error handling here.
       return 1;
   }

   // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

   DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
   for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,
       &DeviceInfoData);i++)
   {
       DWORD DataT;
       LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
       DWORD buffersize = 0;

       //
       // Call function with null to begin with, 
       // then use the returned buffer size (doubled)
       // to Alloc the buffer. Keep calling until
       // success or an unknown failure.
       //
       //  Double the returned buffersize to correct
       //  for underlying legacy CM functions that 
       //  return an incorrect buffersize value on 
       //  DBCS/MBCS systems.
       // 
       while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
           hDevInfo,
           &DeviceInfoData,
           SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
           &DataT,
           (PBYTE)buffer,
           buffersize,
           &buffersize))
       {
           if (GetLastError() == 
               ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {
               // Change the buffer size.
               if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
               // Double the size to avoid problems on 
               // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609. 
               buffer = LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2);
           }
           else
           {
               // Insert error handling here.
               break;
           }
       }

       printf("Result:[%s]\n",buffer);

       if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
   }


   if ( GetLastError()!=NO_ERROR &&
        GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS )
   {
       // Insert error handling here.
       return 1;
   }

   //  Cleanup
   SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

   return 0;
```

}

For some reasons, there are link errors:

```
1>device.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4 referenced in function _main
1>device.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW@28 referenced in function _main
1>device.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12 referenced in function _main
1>device.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsW@16 referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\visual studio 2010\Projects\usb\Debug\usb.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

What they are about? There is no _main() at all.

Comment: Are you linking with Setupapi.lib as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you need to?

Comment: I'm not sure which of the hundred or so previous questions related to this same error I should use as the duplicate in order to close this one. See the "Related" list to the right; any one of them could explain why this type of error happens, which would tell you where to look to resolve it. Please do at least *basic research*, including at least a rudimentary search on the error message, before posting a question here.

Comment: Yes, I added Windows 7.1 SDK's SetupApi.h to C/C++ Directory and SetupApi.lib to linker. But problem remains.

Comment: strange, after closed and reopened the project, the code worked. Not sure what had happened.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, the linker errors are not about missing `main`, but about other functions that are referenced (called) from `main`.

The functions you mentioned in linker errors are from library: **Setupapi.lib**, and you need to include it in Linker settings (Input) of your project.

*Why did it worked on VS re-open?*

Probably simply because you changed the configuration (by mistake). For example from `Win32` to `x64`, and/or from `Debug` to `Release` (or any combination) of these. The other configuration didn't have reference to this library added.